# VB 2008 (Console) "For Each Loop" Lottery Results Comparison

Tags: vb.net

I am facing an issue to perform numbers comparison between the integers inputted by user and random numbers generated by the codes.

Each of the integers input by the user should then be compared with the LOTTO numbers to check for a match. A For each… loop needs to be used to achieve this.

After checking all the 7 user input integers against the LOTTO numbers, the total number of matches should be output to the user. If there are no matches the output should read “LOOSER!”.

Here are my codes, I'm currently only stuck at the comparison portion, and we need to use for each loop to achieve this.

Imports System

Module Lotto

```
Sub Main()

    'Declaration
    Dim numbers(6) As Integer
    Dim IsStarted As Boolean = True

    'Prompt user to enter 
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your 7 lucky numbers from 0 - 9 ONLY")

    'Use Do While Loop to re-iterate the prompts
    Do While IsStarted
        For pos As Integer = 0 To 6
            Console.Write("Enter number {0}: ", pos + 1)
            'How it stores into an array
            numbers(pos) = Console.ReadLine()

            'Check if it is a number: use IsNumberic()
            If IsNumeric(numbers(pos)) Then 'proceed
                'Check if it is NOT 0 < x > 9
                If numbers(pos) < 0 Or numbers(pos) > 9 Then
                    'Don't proceed
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input")
                    IsStarted = True
                    'When any number is invalid, exit the loop
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            IsStarted = False
        Next
    Loop

    'Printing out the array. It can also be written as 
    'For pos = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
    For pos = 0 To 6
        Console.Write(numbers(pos) & " ")
    Next

    Console.WriteLine()
    'Random number generator
    Randomize()
    Dim random_numbers(6) As Integer
    Dim upperbound As Integer = 7
    Dim lowerbound As Integer = 0
    Dim rnd_number As Double = 0

    For pos = 0 To 6
        rnd_number = CInt((upperbound - lowerbound) * Rnd() + lowerbound)
        random_numbers(pos) = rnd_number

        Console.Write(random_numbers(pos) & " ")
    Next

    'Iterate and compare
    Dim isSame As Boolean = False
    Dim pos2 As Integer = 0
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0

    'For check = 0 To 6
    'If numbers(pos2).Equals(random_numbers(pos2)) Then
    For Each number As Integer In numbers
        'Console.WriteLine(pos2 + 1 & ":" & number & ":")
        If number.Equals(random_numbers(pos2)) Then
            'Console.WriteLine("here is the number that matched:" & number & ":")
            isSame = True
            pos2 = pos2 + 1
        End If

        For Each num As Integer In random_numbers
            If random_numbers Is numbers Then
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If

        Next
    Next

    Console.WriteLine()

    'Display result
    If isSame = True Then
        Console.WriteLine("The total numbers of matches are: " & Counter)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("LOOSER!")
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Just a point of pedantry:  "Loser" is spelled with only a single o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            Dim intCursor As Integer = 0

            For Each intNumber As Integer In numbers

                'Assumes first user chosen number must equal 
                'the first random number to be considered a match,
                'the second user number must equal the second random,
                'etc (Ordering is a factor).
                If random_numbers(intCursor) = intNumber Then

                    Counter += 1

                End If

                intCursor += 1

            Next

            If (Counter > 0) Then

                Console.WriteLine("The total numbers of matches are: " & Counter)

            Else

                Console.WriteLine("LOOSER!")

            End If
```

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for the tips, I just want to know why there is an error called "Index was outside the bounds of the array" for "If random_numbers(intCursor) = intNumber Then".

Comment: If the array starts (lower bound) at 0 and you try to grab the -1 index, that error will be thrown.  If the array's upper bound is 6, and you try to grab the 7th index, the error will be thrown.

Comment: Hi sir, I've checked the codes thoroughly and did not see anything wrong with it, I've changed the upperbound to 6 as well, what is the problem actually? Can you please help me?